# net/http webform data post request problems

Tags: go, httpwebrequest

I am very new to golang and I am trying to get an application/x-www-form-urlencoded web request post. I've tried to follow other stack posts in order to manage the request headers, but I still seem to get an error in the Values{} that states
url.Values undefined (type string has no field or method Values)
I have tried to import net/url, but it keeps removing itself from vs code

```
data := url.Values{}
    data.Set("device_id", "xxxx")
    data.Set("guid", "xxxx")
    data.Set("username", "username")
    data.Set("password", "password")
    data.Set("login_attempt_count", "0")

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, strings.NewReader(data.Encode()))

    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "xxx")
    req.Header.Set("Cookie", "xxx")
```

Where am I going wrong in creating a post request?

Comment: "still seem to get an error" Is there an error message? You also don't need to set `req.PostForm`, it is [ignored](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.PostForm). The rest seems to be fine, as long as you check if `err != nil` and display the error message

Comment: You might also need to import `net/url` and use `url.Values{}` like in [this example](https://godoc.org/net/url#Values)

Comment: Thank you for the help I will remove req.PostForm. The error I get is "undefined: Values"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have a string variable named `url` in the same scope. Either rename it to something else, or alias the imported `net/url` package like this:

```golang
import gourl "net/url"
/* ... */
data := gourl.Values{}
```